# How to copy files from PC to Android Device programmatically using USB cable

Tags: android, usb

I have an app that needs copy some files from PC to Android device programmatically through usb cable.
After the user connect an Android device in PC via usb cable and click on button "Copy files from PC to Device", I need to access directory "c:\files_to_app" and copy all files inside that directory to an specific folder in sdcard or root directory Android device.

How is the best approach to achieve it?

Note.
I know that is possible using ctrl+c ctrl+v, but I really need automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will be useful....
To transfer file from pc to android device via USB Socket Communication is best approach.

You have to do some additional step of port forwarding on which the Socket Communication establish.

Look at Tutorial https://github.com/user370305/Android-USB-Communication.

Comment: hemant, in this example I need to have a server and client application. Are there some way to achieve it with only the Android APP, so that I don't need to install one aplication on PC?