# How can I move my python code and assets from a windows Laptop to an android phone?

Tags: python, android, file-transfer, pydroid

I've made a discord.py bot and want to run it on my spare phone with pydroid3 but I cant figure out how to move the main.py file and the 55 asset files (most of them are .png but some are .json and .txt) from my laptop to my phone.

The file structure is

```
bot_folder
║
╠ main.py
╚ assets
  ╠ Text_file_1.txt
  ╠ Text_file_2.txt
  ╠ Text_file_2.txt
  ╠ File_1.json
  ╠ File_2.json
  ╚ Images
    ╚ 49 PNG files
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915325/how-to-copy-files-from-pc-to-android-device-programmatically-using-usb-cable

Comment: @Kelo it would help if i knew where pydroid locates its files. I've already tried connecting my phone to my laptop using a USB cable but only a few folders showed up. Mainly the download folder and some folders for apps and games i have installed. There wasn't a folder for pydroid stuff though.

Comment: Are you viewing hidden files/folders too? - Does PyDroid show you its working directory in the settings?

Comment: @Kelo Yes, I have hidden folders/files enabled. No, it doesn't show me its working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your files to [Github](https://github.com/new) by creating a new reposority. After you uploaded them, reach for your mobile Phone, open Chrome (so that you can request the desktop site of github) and go to that same reposority. By tilting your Phone, you should get a view that looks like the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbFDD.png) below. Click the green Code button, choose "Download ZIP" and download your files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).